# Naming Randoop regression tests

Tags: randoop

I would like to have my regression tests generated by Randoop 4.2 to be named (Something)RandoopTest.java, so I set the command line flag `--regression-test-basename=RandoopTest`.  When I run Randoop, my regression tests all end in RandoopTest**0**.java (note the 0).  For example, when I run the following command,

```
java -classpath C:\sandbox\TestJavaProject\bin;%RANDOOP_JAR%
        randoop.main.Main gentests
        --testclass=org.jaffa.datatypes.Currency
        --junit-package-name=org.jaffa.datatypes
        --junit-output-dir=C:\sandbox\TestJavaProject\src\test\java
        --regression-test-basename=CurrencyRandoopTest
        --time-limit=10
        --junit-reflection-allowed=false
        --flaky-test-behavior=DISCARD
```

I get two files generated, as shown by the console output:

```
Writing regression JUnit tests...
Created file C:\sandbox\TestJavaProject\src\test\java\org\jaffa\datatypes\CurrencyRandoopTest0.java
Created file C:\sandbox\TestJavaProject\src\test\java\org\jaffa\datatypes\CurrencyRandoopTestDriver.java
Wrote regression JUnit tests.
```

Is there an easy way to eliminate the 0?  I'm curious as to why it is there.  I've never noticed any other numbers besides 0 added to the class name.  Currently, our maven scripts are designed to run JUit tests that end in "Test", so the 0 is a bother.  (I know I can modify the scripts to automatically run JUnit tests that end in "Test0", but it would be nicer if I didn't have to.)

Answer (score 1):

Randoop outputs **tests** in files named `...Test0,java`, `...Test1.java`, etc.  By default only [500](https://randoop.github.io/randoop/manual/index.html#option:testsperfile) are put into each numbered file.  Randoop usually creates many tests, and putting all of them into one file would violate Java's limits on file size.

Randoop outputs a **test suite**, which runs all the tests, in a file named `...Test.java` with no number at the end of the file name.

The [example](https://randoop.github.io/randoop/manual/index.html#example_collections) at the beginning of the [Randoop Manual](https://randoop.github.io/randoop/manual/index.html) shows these files and how to use them.

If you have never seen Randoop output more than 500 tests, you might want to [adjust](https://randoop.github.io/randoop/manual/index.html#not-enough-tests-created) the [command-line arguments](https://randoop.github.io/randoop/manual/index.html#command-line-options) to Randoop, to give it more information so that it can generate tests more effectively.

#### Example

As a concrete example of the files, see directory `build/working-directories/naive-collections-test/java/foo/bar/`.  It will exist after you have run Randoop's own test suite.

It contains the files:

```
NaiveRegression.java

NaiveRegression0.java
NaiveRegression1.java
NaiveRegression2.java
```

where the content of `NaiveRegression.java` is:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({ NaiveRegression0.class, NaiveRegression1.class, NaiveRegression2.class })
public class NaiveRegression {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  I don't see any generated class files that end in "Test".  I do see *TestDriver files, that I assume is what you are calling the suite file, since it is running the tests in the *Test0 files. However, I don't see any mentions of "suite" in that file.

Comment: Can you provide a MWE?  That will help others to reporoduce and understand your example.

Comment: I've added a sample command to the questions, together with some of the console output, as you suggested.